# Can prepositions be 'subordinators'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, nonfinite-clause-complementation, subordinators

*"**For her to lose the election** would make me very happy."*

What I think is that here *"For her to lose the election"* is an infinitival non-finite subordinate clause & *"for"* serves as a *marker* for this clause, and *'her'* (which is in objective case) refers to the *understood* subject of the infinitival clause.

Am I right? Now, my question is:

> (1) Is the preposition **"For"** a **"subordinator"** in the above sentence?
>
> (2) Can any *preposition* be treated as a *subordinator* if and when they're *followed by a clause* (finite or non-finite) as their complement?

Comment: The way you've put certain words in bold (**for her to lose**) is disconcertingly different from the words you've put in italics between quotation marks (*to lose the election*)—as well as from what you actually describe. It's as if everything before the block quote just causes confusion.

Comment: Yes to your first question ("her" is the syntactic subject of the infinitival subject clause), but yes and no to the second. Preposition and subordinator are different word classes (parts of speech) so a word can't be both at the same time. You need to distinguish word class and function. In your example "for" belongs to the word class **subordinator** (not prep) and its function is **marker**.

Comment: You shouldn't change the topic sentence after you have received comments. Your first attempt was the correct one, but now you have it wrong! The infinitival subject clause is "For her to lose the election". You need to reverse your edit. See my last comment for an analysis of your original sentence

Comment: I'm confused because I've just read : "A clause can be subordinate to main clause (1) after the subordinator 'that', (2) with relative pronoun, (3) with preposition which may accept a word, a phrase or a clause as its complement. A preposition can be followed by a wide variety of structures.

Comment: You need to change the first line of your question to _What I think is that here "for her to lose the election" is an infinitival.._, as you originally had it. The subordinator "for" and the subject "her" are both part of the infinitival clause.

Comment: Which is the infinitival non-finite clause? (1) "to lose the election" or (2) "For her to lose the election". Please clarify the two.

Comment: _For her to lose the election_ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [*For her to lose the election*] *would make me very happy.*

Yes to your first question. The subject of the bracketed infinitival subject clause is "her", whose referent (antecedent) would have been mentioned earlier in the discourse.

Yes and no to your second question. Preposition and subordinator are different word classes (parts of speech) so a word can't be both at the same time.

You need to distinguish word class and function. In your example "for" belongs to the word class **subordinator** (not prep) and its function is **marker**.

Note: the history of "for" goes back to the preposition "for", but this "for" behaves as a clause subordinator. It does for infinitival clauses with a subject what the subordinator "that" does for declarative content clauses.